# Calling RESTful apis through ajax and angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

If the URL that is to be hit has to be passed variables i.e.
  `API.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?name=[random_city_name]&APPID=[key_value]`,

then what is better to use ajax or angular js.

If I am using ajax then how am I supposed to pass the variable? I am a newbie in this. So, need your help.

Answer (score 4):

Your url seems to have request parameters and assuming you are using angular1

For this, you can use

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: {},
    params : {}
})
```

Put your parameters as a map and $http will take care of creating an url.
Refer $http documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: is it possible to implement this using ajax?

Comment: Ajax internally is `XMLHttpRequest`. So is `$http`. You can use plain AJAX but using angular service would be more preferable. Read the document of $http to better acquaint yourself with it.

Answer (score 1):

> what is better to use ajax or angular js

You can't compare as `AJAX` provides a way to `communicate` (send requests and get responses) with the server `asynchronously` and `AngularJS` used `AJAX` to extends the `2-way` data binding.

To accomplish the above situation we can use Angular [**$http**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

```
var baseUrl = API.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city;
var method = 'GET';
var data = {};
var params = {
   "name":cityName,
   "APPID":key_value
};

$http({
    method: method,
    url: baseUrl,
    params : params,
    data : data
}).then(function mySucces(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.data = response.statusText;
});
```

Comment: if I want to access the data through my HTML page,then is the same syntax correct i.e. $scope.data? I am very new to angular and am not familiar with the syntax.Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can access it in html using angular expression `{{ data }}` or using ng-repeat if it is an array `ng-repeat="item in data"`.

Comment: I meant if I have an input box in html, where I enter the city and I have to access this city in angular.js. Then what am I supposed to do?

Comment: `<input type="text" ng-model="cityName">`, then to access model value : in controller you can access through `$scope.cityName` and in html you can directly access using angular expression `{{ cityName }}`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use angular $http service and pass your params like below.

var UserInfo = function() {
    $scope.userID = "1111";
    var req ={
        "method":"GET",
        "url": someURL + $scope.userID,
        "withCredentials":true
    };
    $http(req).then(function(response) {
        alert('success');
    }, function(response) {
        alert('error');
    });
};
```